# Pattern recognition and machine learning (Bishop) - Figure 5.3: Something is wrong with the sine function

Tags: neural-networks

[image]
In Figure 5.3, Pattern recognition and machine learning (Bishop), the author says he fitted 4 function: f(x) = x^2; f(x) = sin(x) ; f(x) = abs(x); f(x) = Heaviside(x), using 50 points chosen uniformly over the range [-1; 1]. And he did it with a 2-layer neural networks with 3 hidden units, and with "tanh" activation function. The problem is with the sine function: In the figure there are obviously a local minima and a local maxima, but we know that those 2 points are : x = pi/2 and x = -pi/2, and they are not in the range [-1; 1]. So how are we going to fit the sine function with the local minima (and maxima) if we don't even have any information about them ? Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing about this in [the 2011 errata](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/prml-errata-1st-20110921.pdf) to Bishop's *PRML.* If you believe that this is an error, you could contact the author.

Answer (score 2):

As it appears in other scratches of code (see https://github.com/ctgk/PRML for Python), it's actually $sin(\pi x)$.

May you have a nice day!

Comment: Very good github page +1

Comment: But is this the official page?

Comment: Not sure. Wouldn't think so...! But pretty good anyway.